# What's different between two ways of defining React Component?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

There're 2 ways to define a React component.

First one is like below.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      someState: false
    }
    this._handleOnChangeState = this._handleOnChangeState.bind(this)
  }

  _handleOnChangeState (e) {
    this.setState({ someState: e.target.value })
  }
  ....

}
```

Second one is like below.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    someState: false
  }

  _handleOnChangeState = (e) => {
    this.setState({ someState: e.target.value })
  }
  ....

}
```

These two codes are the same function, but I guess there's some different something like memory usage or etc.

Can someone make it clearly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second is not standard ES.

Comment: But it works, and it can be seen in many examples.

Comment: It works because you use it with a transpiler that is configured to transpile stage 3 proposals.

Comment: Other than that - there are really few reasons for one to be "better" than the other.

Comment: I wonder about the really few reasons!!

Comment: Those are implementation details, which is specific to a particular engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new proposal (class fields) for ES which is in [stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) right now. To run a code written in this way you need a transpiler like Babel and an appropriate plugin.

Before transpile:

```
class A {
  static color = "red";
  counter = 0;

  handleClick = () => {
    this.counter++;
  }
}
```

After transpile (with stage 2 on Babel Repl):

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.counter = 0;

    this.handleClick = () => {
      this.counter++;
    };
  }

}
A.color = "red";
```

In addition to the official proposal [2ality blog post](http://2ality.com/2017/07/class-fields.html) is a good source to see what are the details.

Here is a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/6q0rov/es_proposal_class_fields/) if you have time to read the discussion storm what is the reason behind this proposal :)

The arrow function here is a different story. You can use instance properties without constructor and mix your code with standard functions. But when you want to use something like that `this` won't work:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { bar: "baz"}

  foo() { console.log(this.state.bar) };

  render() {
    return <div><button onClick={this.foo}>Click</button></div>;
  }
}
```

We need to bind our function in somehow like:

```
return <div><button onClick={this.foo.bind(this)}>Click</button></div>
```

But, binding our function in a JSX prop is no so good since it will create our function in each render.

One way to do this nicely bind in our constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.foo = this.foo.bind( this );
  }
```

But, if I have to write a constructor what is the point? This is why you see arrow functions everywhere where we define the classes like your second example. No need to bind to function thanks to arrow functions. But it is not directly related to this new proposal I think.

Comment: I feel more clear. But still I wonder if there're some disadvantages when I use arrow functions instead of normal function with binding in constructor.

Comment: @Benjamin Yrs, but rarely: arrow functions are duplicated across instances. Irrelevant under most circumstances, but if you had a huge number of duplicate components on a page maybe it'd matter a tiny bit.

Comment: Some says or thinks there might be some performance issues with arrow functions. I'm not so experienced but like @DaveNewton explained it, there could be some issues depending on your app. But I like the arrow functions and this new proposal. As a learner up to now performance is not a big issue for me, code readibility is more important then performance right now :)

Comment: @DaveNewton the other implementation creates a function per instance as well. So from that perspective it really is not different.

Comment: @zerkms Oh right, wasn't even thinking :( Was talking about general case. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the traditional approach and the second one is when you [babel-transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin.
In the second type babel does the same thing under the hood, therefore it is a matter of convenience.