# Instance property in React ES6 class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

How come in React you can define state like below:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  state = { foo: 'bar' }
}
```

But in order to define other instance properties you need to do it in the constructor or other functions? As in, you can't do this:

```
 class Test extends React.Component {
  myField = 0;

  render() {
    myField++
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `this.myField++`. Though syntax is wrong since you must return something from render like:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  myField = 0;

  render() {
    return <div>this.myField++</div>
  }
}
```

You won't see `1` there because React first sees myField's value and render it.

But I think the actual question is not about how we use it. It is about a new proposal for ES: class-fields. Here is an explanation for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50789811/7060441

> This is a new proposal (class fields) for ES which is in [stage 3][1]
>   right now. To run a code written in this way you need a transpiler
>   like Babel and an appropriate plugin.
>
> Before transpile:
>
> ```
> class A {
>   static color = "red";
>   counter = 0;
>
>   handleClick = () => {
>     this.counter++;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> After transpile (with stage 2 on Babel Repl):
>
> ```
> class A {
>   constructor() {
>     this.counter = 0;
>
>     this.handleClick = () => {
>       this.counter++;
>     };
>   }
>
> }
> A.color = "red";
> ```
>
> In addition to the official proposal [2ality blog post][2] is a good
>   source to see what are the details.
>
> Here is a [reddit post][3] if you have time to read the discussion
>   storm what is the reason behind this proposal :)
>
> The arrow function here is a different story. You can use instance
>   properties without constructor and mix your code with standard
>   functions. But when you want to use something like that `this` won't
>   work:
>
> ```
> class App extends React.Component {
>   state = { bar: "baz"}
>
>   foo() { console.log(this.state.bar) };
>
>   render() {
>     return <div><button onClick={this.foo}>Click</button></div>;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> We need to bind our function in somehow like:
>
> ```
> return <div><button onClick={this.foo.bind(this)}>Click</button></div>
> ```
>
> But, binding our function in a JSX prop is no so good since it will
>   create our function in each render.
>
> One way to do this nicely bind in our constructor:
>
> ```
> constructor(props) {
>     super(props);
>     this.foo = this.foo.bind( this );
>   }
> ```
>
> But, if I have to write a constructor what is the point? This is why
>   you see arrow functions everywhere where we define the classes like
>   your second example. No need to bind to function thanks to arrow
>   functions. But it is not directly related to this new proposal I
>   think.
>
> [1]: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields   [2]:
>   http://2ality.com/2017/07/class-fields.html   [3]:
>   https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/6q0rov/es_proposal_class_fields/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  myField = 0;

  render() {
    this.myField++ // use this to access class properties
  }
}
```

---

But avoid using normal class properties and use state properties like in your first example. So, that you can:

1. Re-render component when necessary using `this.setState()`.
2. Force update and re-render the component using `this.forceUpdate()`.
3. Re-render the parent component.
4. Change properties from React's lifecycle hook for eg `shouldComponentUpdate()`
5. Not allow to mutate the property from outside the scope for eg. if
   you are using normal properties, then you can change it from the
   browser console.

---

You might need normal properties like in scenario of:

Set timer as normal class properties in the constructor

```
this.timer = setTimeout(..)
```

Clear timer in componentWillUnmount

```
componentWillUnmount (clearTimeout(this.timer))
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you can, but instead of `myField++`, change it to `this.myField++`. An example created on snack @ [here](https://snack.expo.io/HkcGEwyWQ)

It really has nothing much to do with React but more on general class concept in JS. Find out [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) about class

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is syntactic sugar. Nothing "new" about JavaScript in this regard. It abstracts out the concept of creating a constructor function for the sole purpose of declaring variables within the `class`'s context and does it for you. These are equivalent:

```
class Sample {
  dog = 1
}

class Sample {
  constructor() {
    this.dog = 1
  }
}
```